# LineNumberReader mark EOF

Tags: java, eof

I have a remote file which I read with an `URLConnection`, so `RandomAccessFile` isn't relevant. I need to read this file until an EOF occurs, then wait some time. During this time some new lines will be added to the file and then I'm going to continue my reading from the place where I stopped to read (previous EOF). That is mean I nead in next time to read only the new lines added to the file.

As I understand I can do it with `LineNumberReader`, using the `mark()` method. But how could I mark EOF and then return to this mark again, when new lines will be added?

Comment: When new lines are added to the file and your program reads those, would it be reading them from the same URLConnection or a newly opened URLConnection?

Answer (score 1):

The only way you can get end of stream from a `URLConnection` is if the sender closes the connection, or shuts it down, or sends chunks that specify a final chunk, or achieves the length sent in the `Content-Length` header. In any of those events there will never be any more data. What you're asking is impossible.

Comment: I get EOF by reading line by line until readLine() returns null.My question was about marking.